# Django admin error ValidationError: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Tags: django, django-admin

Hi I am creating an model admin with dynamic inline's.

```
class InlineProfile(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile
#     max_num = 1

class InlineProfileOne(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TableOne
#     max_num = 1

class InlineProfileTwo(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TableTwo
#     max_num = 1

class UserDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineProfile]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        up=UserProfile.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
        if (up.job_type.job_type==1):
            self.inlines.append(InlineProfileOne)
        elif (up.job_type.job_type==2):
            self.inlines.append(InlineProfileTwo)
        return obj and super(UserDisplay, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj) or []

#     def get_formsets(self, request, obj):
#         print obj
#         for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
#             yield inline.get_formset(request, obj)

    list_display = [f.name for f in LCUser._meta.fields]
    field_set = list(list_display)
    field_set.remove('id')
    field_set.remove('api_key')
    field_set.remove('api_secret')

    readonly_fields=['last_login_ip','last_login_timestamp','created_at','updated_at']

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': field_set,

        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('api_key', 'api_secret'),
        }),
    )

    search_fields=list_display
    list_filter=['user_type','profile_complete']
    list_editable=list(list_display)
    list_editable.remove('id')
    list_editable.remove('updated_at')
    list_editable.remove('created_at')
    list_editable.remove('last_login_timestamp')
    list_editable.remove('last_login_ip')

    class Meta:
        model = LCUser
```

On display I somtimes see two inline rows instead of one and when I try to update it I get "ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with"

Comment: You may have to render the ManagementForm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Comment: Just to note, if you have inlines in an admin form, and you make changes before the inlines have loaded (slow connection), you will get this error.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. looks like I forgot to initialize the inlinse variable. So everytime I clicked on an object it added the same inline model again, which caused errors when I tried to save it.

Comment: The answer is not very clear. It would be very considerate to add more details on the step that caused and fixed the issue.

Comment: The answer isn't clear at lease a code comparison needed